# Navigation app in Android, populating data

Tags: android, navigation

I am developing an Android App on which I get a list of events from DB and put them on a ListView. Every item can be clicked to see event details and every detail can be clicked to see statistics on that detail. What is the best approach for populating data? I have an activity that launches a new instance of the same activity to populate the new ListView.

Is it the best thing to do or is it better to do it in another way? I've done something similar in iPhone with the NavigationController and I would like to replicate the navigation forward-backward in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you have a look at the [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) sample, which is similar in what you are trying to do:

- It demonstrates how to connect to database
- It will teach you how to create a custom url describing your data and how to use this with Intents
- It demonstrates switching from a listview to an itemview
- It shows how to add/edit/delete items

What it won't show is the statistics view you want for the events. If I were you, I would create a different ListActivity for this and not reuse the main list view.